# Php to Json File append to ul Ajax Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

Hi I'm having problem appending PHP Json file to ul in my html file. I have done it using data-url connected to a txt file but I want it to be connected to my Mysql database. Here is a working sample using data-url :

```
 $.ajax({
        url: $container.data("url")
      , dataType: "text"
      , success: function(data) {
        var persons= data.toString().split('\r\n');

        for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
          var person = persons[i];
          person && $content.append("<li><b>" + person + "</b></li>");
        }

        $item           = $("#container ul li"),

        //Pre-caculate the count of items
        itemCount       = $item.size();
        //Clone the contents
        $content.append($content.html());
      }
    });
```

Here is what im trying to do using Json

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'php/index.php',
    dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
       $content.append("<li><b>" + item.name + "</b></li>");
    });
});
```

Here is my PHP file connected to my database:

```
<?php

$host    = 'localhost';
$db      = 'made';
$user    = 'root';
$pass    = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];


$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$sql  = $dbh->query("SELECT name FROM employee");
$rows = array();
while ($row = $sql->fetchall()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);


?>
```

Output:

```
[[{"name":"JAMES, MARY A."},{"name":"CARDINAL, GRACE S."},{"name":"RAMON, CHELYND."},{"name":"APPLE, KATHRINE C."},{"name":"JOHNSON , WILSON J."},{"name":"BILL, ANDREW P."}]]
```

Comment: What does your PHP JSON file look like? It should be a String of JSON on the PHP page. Usually data is handled with PHP getting data from MySQL, then JSON is returned to JavaScript using `echo json_encode($assocArray);`.

Comment: Hi I've updated my post

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is the php call my only error how about my ajax call is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Change `$rows = array(); while ($row = $sql->fetchall()) { $rows[] = $row; }` to echo `json_encode($sql->fetchAll());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for [fetchAll()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

> PDOStatement::fetchAll() returns an array containing **all of the remaining rows** in the result set. The array represents each row as either an array of column values or an object with properties corresponding to each column name. An empty array is returned if there are zero results to fetch, or FALSE on failure.

Because of this, you don't need to do a loop here. It ends up creating a redundant loop that adds another array. (Notice the `[[` at the start?) Just edit your code, and remove the loop:

```
$sql  = $dbh->query("SELECT name FROM employee");
$rows = $sql->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Thank you. How about the ajax call am I doing something wrong in that part?

Comment: It looks fine. With the changes, it should work properly. Do a `console.log(data);` and verify the data is correct.